# Dynamic min/max FormGroup validation

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to validate a form with some fields. Two of them allow an integer value. Now the first of these two fields defines the minimum value of the second field and the second field defines the maximum value of the first one.

When one of these rules is violated both form controls should result in an INVALID state and therefore should also re-validate if one of the two values changed.

How can I achieve something like this using the FormGroup Validation of Angular?

I got something like this working but when I entered something like "7" and "6" (which would be invalid) and changed it to "5" and "6" the second field (containing "6") was still invalid.

Hope I didn't explain my issue too complicated :)

Comment: Sorry for the automatic message, but I answered this question some days ago. Look at both answers, see what suits you best (and preferably use the validated one).

Comment: Thanks this is exaclity what I needed. The second answer solved what I wanted. Hours of googling and yet I never found this question...

Comment: That's a huge coincidence actually, but glad it helped you ! Be sure to upvote the answers that you found useful, to let other know that it works

Comment: Just did. One more question though: If I set the second value lower than the first your stackblitz shows the error message correctly. However if I then correct the first value by setting it lower than the second value, the error message still remains although it would be a valid value.

Comment: I see that, it seems to be another issue : the form isn't applying the validators of the fields that are not beinf modified. Maybe you should try with `updateValueAndValidity` to manually trigger the validators ?

Comment: I've managed to make it work : [here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lz5msy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). Only issue : Since bith fields are in error, it will display both messages. But hey, at this point that's not finding an issue, that's optimization ;)

Comment: Perfect! This just works as I expected it to! Thank you so much :)